# Does iOS 14 have some breaking changes that disable vertical scroll for Collection View?

Tags: swift, ios14

An app I'm building utilizes a vertical collection view and it was working fine. I updated my phone to iOS 14 and vertical scrolling seems to be disabled and I can't tap or interact with any of the buttons in my collection view cell.

Is there some collection view configuration that needs to be added specific to iOS 14 API updates?

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Close as a duplicate for the "can't tap or interact with any of the buttons" part, as there is a known change in iOS 14 that would cause this, if your code was always wrong (which it presumably was). Consider asking the "vertical scrolling" part separately — but even then, you need to give instructions for reproducing the problem.

Comment: @matt thank you very much! Your answer on the duplicate solved it.